# Using wrap in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using the wrap utility in Oracle to hide my code. I first compile the `pks` and `pkb` files in SQL Developer. Then I use the wrap utility on the command prompt:

```
C:\DatabaseV2\Packages>D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\wrap   iname=USERACCESS.PKB  oname=USERACCESS.PKE

PL/SQL Wrapper: Release 11.2.0.2.0- Production on Tue Jun 10 11:42:23 2014

Copyright (c) 1993, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Processing USERACCESS.PKB to USERACCESS.PKE
```

But when I go back to the packages in SQL developer, the body is still not encrypted? I tried restarting SQL Developer but no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [wrap utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/wrap.htm) creates a new source file with obfuscated code. You can see in your case that it has created a file called `USERACCESS.PKE`. It does not load that into the database:

> The wrap utility need not connect to Oracle Database (in fact, it cannot connect to Oracle Database).

You have to manually load that `.pke` file, either from SQL Developer, or from SQL*Plus or some other client.

Bear in mind that you won't be able to edit the package body through SQL Developer once the wrapped version has been loaded.